HP 360 Spectre running Ubuntu reboots all the time instead of shutting down
I have Ubuntu on my HP Spectre 360. and recently, the behavior changed:
When I click on shutting down, it shuts down and 2 seconds later it restarts. Same when I don't touch it for few minutes, it goes on power saving mode, the screen goes black and usually the laptop "sleeps." But in my case, when I reactivate it, all my apps are closed, and unsaved, like it rebooted.
I thought I messed up my Ubuntu distribution, so I erased the previous version and reinstalled it, losing all my files, but nothing changed. Same behavior.
Any one knows how I could revert to original behavior: It shuts down when I click on shutting down, and it goes in sleep mode, does not restart when you don't touch the laptop for 5 minutes for instance?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have there been any firmware or BIOS updates lately? Is S3 sleep, or other sleep state, disabled in BIOS?

I've updated my question. About the BIOS, I did not change anything before it happens. I checked for some times all the options in the BIOS and nothing was a clear option to solving this issue.
